# Is there anyway to modify the below cell references as a range?

Tags: excel, vba, range, cell

I am currently utilising the below code in my sheets. However I am expanding to add more variables which increases the number of cells I'll have to reference dramatically.

```
Sub Inventory_Update()

Dim sht1 As Worksheet, sht2 As Worksheet

Set sht1 = Worksheets("Datasheet")
Set sht2 = Worksheets("Inventory")

With sh2

  sht2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = sht1.Range("A1450").Value
sht2.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = sht1.Range("B1450").Value
sht2.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = sht1.Range("C1450").Value
sht2.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = sht1.Range("D1450").Value
sht2.Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = sht1.Range("E1450").Value
sht2.Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = sht1.Range("F1450").Value
sht2.Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = sht1.Range("G1450").Value
sht2.Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = sht1.Range("H1450").Value
sht2.Cells(Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = sht1.Range("I1450").Value
sht2.Cells(Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = sht1.Range("J1450").Value
sht2.Cells(Rows.Count, 11).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = sht1.Range("K1450").Value
sht2.Cells(Rows.Count, 12).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = sht1.Range("L1450").Value
sht2.Cells(Rows.Count, 13).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = sht1.Range("M1450").Value
sht2.Cells(Rows.Count, 14).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = sht1.Range("N1450").Value
sht2.Cells(Rows.Count, 15).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = sht1.Range("O1450").Value
sht2.Cells(Rows.Count, 16).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = sht1.Range("P1450").Value
sht2.Cells(Rows.Count, 17).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = sht1.Range("Q1450").Value
sht2.Cells(Rows.Count, 18).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = sht1.Range("R1450").Value
sht2.Cells(Rows.Count, 19).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = sht1.Range("S1450").Value
sht2.Cells(Rows.Count, 20).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = sht1.Range("T1450").Value
sht2.Cells(Rows.Count, 21).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = sht1.Range("U1450").Value
sht2.Cells(Rows.Count, 22).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = sht1.Range("V1450").Value
sht2.Cells(Rows.Count, 23).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = sht1.Range("W1450").Value
sht2.Cells(Rows.Count, 24).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = sht1.Range("X1450").Value
sht2.Cells(Rows.Count, 25).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = sht1.Range("Y1450").Value
sht2.Cells(Rows.Count, 26).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = sht1.Range("Z1450").Value
sht2.Cells(Rows.Count, 27).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = sht1.Range("AA1450").Value
sht2.Cells(Rows.Count, 29).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = sht1.Range("AB1450").Value
sht2.Cells(Rows.Count, 30).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = sht1.Range("AC1450").Value
sht2.Cells(Rows.Count, 31).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = sht1.Range("AD1450").Value
sht2.Cells(Rows.Count, 32).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = sht1.Range("AE1450").Value
sht2.Cells(Rows.Count, 33).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = sht1.Range("AF1450").Value
sht2.Cells(Rows.Count, 34).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = sht1.Range("AG1450").Value
sht2.Cells(Rows.Count, 35).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = sht1.Range("AH1450").Value
sht2.Cells(Rows.Count, 36).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = sht1.Range("AI1450").Value
```

Is it possible to use a range? Hopefully someone can advise how to utilize it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: So these values are not all expected to end up in the same row?  It's not clear why you take this approach.

Comment: `sht2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(1, 36).Value = sht1.Range("A1450").Resize(1, 36).Value`  assuming they're all meant to end up in the same row.

Comment: Hello, yes they are are expected to end up in the same row. Its a legacy file and the owner left unfortunately.

Comment: What I posted in the comment should do that.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help on it. I have a last question, if after 'Const NUM_COLS As Long = 36' there is a cell with fomula and i want to have a gap before continuing onto the next cell, how can I adjust the "Const" along the script to continue at number 40 for example?

Comment: You'd need to perform two operations to do that - add another for the "after the gap" columns

Comment: Thanks for the tip, i'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub Inventory_Update()
    Const NUM_COLS As Long = 36
    Dim sht1 As Worksheet, sht2 As Worksheet

    Set sht1 = Worksheets("Datasheet") 'ThisWorkbook
    Set sht2 = Worksheets("Inventory")


    sht2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(1, NUM_COLS).Value = _
                 sht1.Range("A1450").Resize(1, NUM_COLS).Value
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Inventory_Update()

Dim sht1 As Worksheet, sht2 As Worksheet
Dim sht2_start_row As Long

Set sht1 = Worksheets("Datasheet")
Set sht2 = Worksheets("Inventory")

sht2_start_row = 1450

With sh2
    For i = 0 To 10
        sht2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1 + i).End(xlUp).Offset(1).value = sht1.Cells(1, sht2_start_row + i).value
    Next
End With
```

Comment: Hello, I tried this out but its not pasting the values onto the destination sheet.